# How to make persistent process that continues after app being killed in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, android-workmanager

I have a process in my android app that does some calculations and saves its result to cache. It takes approximately 10 seconds and it is started after application launch.

The problem is when user kills app by swiping in recent applications list. The process is being stopped along with the app, while I want it to continue its calculations.

I tried to use service with STICKY_START and it kind of does the job, however the process is being started from the beginning, but I'm afraid this might be killed by some manufacturers' software.

I also tried to implement OneTimeWorkRequest, but this instead of being continued is scheduled for another restart. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Are there any other options to achieve persistent process?

Answer (score 0):

Try WorkManager.  If you initiate a task in WorkManager it will continue even if the app is killed.

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: I tried, but as I said, OneTimeWorkRequest doesnt continue after app is killed, it is just scheduled for application restart.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

    {
        OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AppsWorker.class).setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();
        mWorkManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
                AppsWorker.class.getCanonicalName(),
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, //Existing Periodic Work policy
                mRequest);
    }
```

// AppsWorker.class - your class which extends Worker

Comment: Yes, but I want it to execute only once, not every one hour. OneTimeWorkRequest should do the job, but instead of working in the background task is scheduled to continue after application restart.